# Understanding a diode's power rating

Tags: power, diodes, passive-components

I thought I found a suitable diode for a project I am working on, it has the correct current and voltage ratings, but then I noticed the power rating and now I am lost.

The diode in question is the dual [MMBD4448HT](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30263.pdf) I like this because it is extremely small and I can use it to supply my circuit from two sources. The circuit in question has a maximum current of 400mA but a typical usage of around 250mA. Its input voltage is 10-30V so quite the range. So two supplies, diode-OR'ed into one circuit.

Will I exceed the power limit of 150mW at these voltages?

How do I calculate it myself?

Comment: Include a schematic that shows **how** you will be using these diodes.

Answer (score 2):

Power = Voltage * Current

I'm assuming that you have a continuous forward current of 400 mA.

Note that these diodes are very small so they heat up very quickly. So even if the current is 400 mA for a short time, that would need to be **really short** like less than 1 second if you wait a long time (many minutes) before doing that again.

Now look up the forward voltage for 400 mA: around 1.2 V (depends on temperature, I just picked a value, that's good enough for OK/not OK).

So Power dissipation = 0.4 A * 1.2 V = 0.48 W = 480 mW which is much more than 150 mW.

So no, this is **not OK**. You are exceeding the power limit of these diodes.

These diodes are designed for a lower continuous current than what you need.

Maybe a **Schottky** diode is an option as these have a lower forward voltage drop and therefore lower power dissipation.

Comment: Do be aware that Schottky diodes have much higher reverse leakage, and much lower breakdown voltage, if either matters for your application. If you do need a significant breakdown voltage or you're concerned about leakage, you should look into pn diodes that are rated for more power. Consider ones in SMA or SMB packages, rather than the tiny low-power SOT-23.